# create a random rectangle with limited a limited area

Tags: c#, random, range, shapes, area

I need to generate a rectangle with random dimentions, but I want to avoid generating any rectangles above a specified area limit. Notice I said area, I can't simply have a random value within a certain range be generated for each axis independently.

In practice I need to generate a set of two values that have a product within a certain range.

Heres kinda what i'd need:

```
//generates any 2 numbers that multiply to less then 30 and more then 0
randomArea = Vector2 Random.Area(0, maxArea)
```

(Answers preferably in C#)

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? If you already know what area you want, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Seems like you can generate one side/random and then determine what the max of the other side is and then generate that random.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know how i didn't think of that

Comment: Note that this will not create an even distribution. To improve that you could alternate which side to create first..

Comment: See following :            Random rand = new Random();
            const int MAX_AREA = 30;
            int width = rand.Next(1, 30);
            int height = rand.Next(1, MAX_AREA / width);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly generate the area.
Randomly generate one axis.
Divide the area by the axis, and you will get the other axis.